# How to store input data using php into text file and get data from text file?

Tags: javascript, php, persistence

I'm gonna store a current input data in text file, and get data from same file. for example: In **form.php** I've input form:

```
<form name="formData" method="POST" action="landing.php">
<p>NEW DATA:</p>
<input type="text" id="new" name="newdata" />
<p>CURRENT DATA:</p>
<input type="text" id="current" name="current" />
<input type="submit" name="Invia" Value="Invia i dati">
<input type="reset" id="reset" name="Reset" Value="Reset">
</form>
```

and in the **landing.php** I've this:

```
<?php
$newdata = $_POST['newdata'];
$current = $_POST['current'];
$file = 'box.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($file);
$output  = str_replace($current, $newdata, $xml);
file_put_contents($file, $output);
?>
```

As you can see, after submit current data and new data, xml file will be saved with new data.

Here is my question:

How can I store **$newdata** in text file after submit, and it will show it in **form.php** as **$current**  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code on form.php

```
  $file = 'box.xml';
  $xml = file_get_contents($file);
```

After this, below the CURRENT DATA, add

```
  <input type="text" id="current" name="current" value="<?php echo $xml; ?>" />
```

**EDIT**
On Landing.php

```
   <?php
     $newdata = $_POST['newdata'];
     $file = 'box.xml';
     /* there is no need of this code
     $current = $_POST['current'];
     $xml = file_get_contents($file);
     $output  = str_replace($current, $newdata, $xml);*/
     file_put_contents($file, $newdata);
    ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, you code just show everything inside of xml file, not specific data for $current...  we need to use text file to store newdata then it will use it for current data, I'm looking for that sir

Comment: I would need more information. Do you want to replace the current data with the new one and display it as current?

Comment: Yes, In this case because it's just only one data, I don't wanna use DB, so, how can I store "new data" into "text file" and then I will restore data from text file in  form.php as "current data" ... so in this case, that "text file" must be overwritten. how to do it?

Comment: file_put_contents will replace the existing content with the new one. Therefore, you do not need str_replace.

Comment: In the xml file, there are many data,  this particular method is just for to change css class name, thats why I had to use  str_replace to search base on name and replace it to new name. anyway in this case, I've to find a solution to store new name in text file and I will show it as current name, this is only way for this otherwise I'll have to use db.

Comment: I think so I got a way to store it into text file, could you please tell me how to overwrite text file using file_get_contents?